# Trouble getting the latest data from my redux store in react app

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
  const { categoryId } = useParams();
  const { clinicsById, clinicsList, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.clinics
  );
  const clinics = clinicsList.map((clinicId) => clinicsById[clinicId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchClinicsForCategory({ categoryId }));
  }, [categoryId, dispatch]);

  return <div>{clinics}</div>;
```

Basically, this component displays different data depending on the categoryId.
But after the first render, consequent renders to different categoryId are showing the previous state.
In this scenario, I believe the state from the previous render displays without waiting for the new state to arrive. FetchClinicsForCategory() makes an API call to grab the new data. How can I always show the latest data? When I print the clinics to the console, I can see that the new data arrives.

https://streamable.com/5m5o6u

This is the reducer code. My action is making a call to an API and getting the data and passing it to this reducer.

```
getClinicsSuccess(state, action) {
      const clinics = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
      state.clinicsList = clinics.map((clinic) => clinic.clinicId);

      clinics.forEach((clinic) => {
        state.clinicsById[clinic.clinicId] = clinic;
      });
    }
```

Edit: Added a recording of the issue. You can see that even though I click on a category with 1 service, it shows the multiple services from the previous time I rendered the page.

Edit: Added reducer code.

Comment: Can you please provide an example output?

Comment: What does your `fetchClinicsForCategory` do? And how is fetching handled in reducer? Chances are you mutate the array so when loading completes selector gets the same object and does not trigger an update. To check it try to put your `map` into selector.

Answer (score 0):

So it wasn't an issue with Redux... 
I had a separate state keeping a list of filtered clinics and that was the list being rendered instead of my actual new data. I'll need to rework the logic. Thanks for the suggestions!